# CSS3 Animation Resetting

Tags: css, animation

I just learnt about CSS3 Animations, and I made this fade in effect, but once the animation finishes it returns to its original place, how can I make it stay there?

also the animation seems a little rough is there a better way of writing this so that it appears smoother?

```
.logo {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
animation-name: down;
animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes down {
0% {top: 0px; opacity: 0;}
30% {top: 50px;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop an element at the `completion of animation`, so for that you have to include `animation-fill-mode` as below,

So using `animation-fill-mode:forwards` it stop the position of elements as soon as `last frame` is executed. There are other properties too and such as `forwards, backwards, both` and such more.

But in your `animation` you didn't declare the end of `animation` i.e. at `100%` where to stop, so it goes back to `0px`,

Check both examples below,

**Example - 1**

```css
.logo {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
animation-name: down;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
background:#ccc;
top:0px;
}

@keyframes down {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  30%{
    top:30px;
  }
  100%{
    top:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">

</div>
```

**Example - 2**

```css
.logo {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
animation-name: down;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
background:#ccc;
top:0px;
}

@keyframes down {
  from{
    opacity:0;
  }
  to{
    top:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome @MDAWG :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `animation-fill-mode: forwards` which will prevent your animation getting reset.

```
.logo {
  /* other properties */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```